# Converting long format flat file to wide in R

Tags: r, reshape, long-integer, tidyr

I have a household and member dataset in one long flat format. There is a fixed number of members and each corresponds to a column. For simplicity, assume 2 members per household and assume 2 questions are asked for the members- age (Q1), gender(Q2).

The file format looks as given below:

```
HHID, MEM_ID_1, MEM_ID_2, AGE_1, AGE_2, GENDER_1, GENDER_2
1     1         2         50     45     M         F
```

And I want to convert it to the following format:

```
HHID MEM_ID AGE GENDER
1    1      50   M
1    2      45   F
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say our data frame is **test**

```
dput(test)

structure(list(HHID = 1L, MEM_ID_1 = 1L, MEM_ID_2 = 2L, AGE_1 = 50L, 
AGE_2 = 45L, GENDER_1 = structure(1L, .Label = "Male", class = "factor"), 
GENDER_2 = structure(1L, .Label = "Female", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
```

-1L))

You could try the reshape function on this data frame as below:

```
reshape(test, direction = "long",
        varying = list(c("MEM_ID_1","MEM_ID_2"), c("AGE_1","AGE_2"), c( "GENDER_1","GENDER_2")),
        v.names = c("MEM_ID","AGE","GENDER"),
        idvar = 'HHID')
```

The reshape() function comes from the base R. Broadly speaking, it can simultaneously melt over multiple sets of variables, by using the varying parameter and setting the direction to **long**.

For example in your case we have a list of three **vectors** of variable names to the varying argument:

```
varying = list(c("MEM_ID_1","MEM_ID_2"), c("AGE_1","AGE_2"), c( "GENDER_1","GENDER_2"))
```

The output is below:

```
    HHID time MEM_ID AGE GENDER
1.1   1    1     1   50   Male
1.2   1    2     2   45   Female
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyr::gather()`, `tidyr::separate()`, and `tidyr::spread()` in order. Here `household` is the name of your data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### 1. `gather`

First, `tidyr::gather()`. Then you can get the below result.

```
household %>% 
  gather(-HHID, key = domestic, value = value)
#>   HHID domestic value
#> 1    1 MEM_ID_1     1
#> 2    1 MEM_ID_2     2
#> 3    1    AGE_1    50
#> 4    1    AGE_2    45
#> 5    1 GENDER_1     M
#> 6    1 GENDER_2     F
```

Now all you have to do is

1. separate `domestic` column at `_[0-9]`: In regular expression, `_(?=[0-9])`
2. Changing the format into the wide format, you can see the output you want.

### 2. Conclusion: entire code

```
household %>% 
  gather(-HHID, key = domestic, value = value) %>% # long data
  separate(domestic, into = c("domestic", "vals"), sep = "_(?=[0-9])") %>% # separate the digit
  spread(domestic, value) %>% # wide format
  select(HHID, MEM_ID, AGE, GENDER, -vals) # just arranging columns, and excluding needless column
#>   HHID MEM_ID AGE GENDER
#> 1    1      1  50      M
#> 2    1      2  45      F
```